# Unable to Found a Dashboard in Sonarqube community edition 7.0

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am new to sonarqube.I have seen other blogs they have Dashboards and widgets to setup their project. but i coundnt find them in my sonarqube and no plugins are available.Any suggestions on setting up dashboards on  sonarqube community edition 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dashboards were removed in SonarQube 6.2. That's why you're not finding a link.

Comment: is there any way to install that one?

Comment: No. You can downgrade SonarQube to 6.1, but it is a solution of a kind "do it never".